# Behat - Step definition for Dynamic year along with Copyright

Tags: drupal, behat

I am testing this Drupal site using Behat.
I am stuck with this particular issue. So my problem statemet is:

```
As an Anonymous User, I should be able to see Copyright with Dynamic year in the footer region of any page.
```

Is there any contributd module or inbult code i can use?
Use of `And I should see current year in the copyright text` is out of scope.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Why don’t you create a step in an extension file that looks for the string in the page? As for the year just check for the current year by getting it from php time function.

Comment: too much detail in the step, just say `the copyright is displayed` and behind it just format the text based on dynamic year